# Using integers in a string Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, while-loop

My code:

```
number = 0
while True:
     number +=1
     url = url + '?curpage={}'.format(number)
     html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

My issue: I have a while loop and within the while loop, I have a URL. For each step, I want URL to change to:

```
url?curpage=1
url?curpage=2
...
```

What I am getting:

```
url?curpage=1
url?curpage=1?curpage=2
...
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What does this `url = url + ` do?

Comment: I think I just resolved the issue by changing the variable name to url1= url + ...

Comment: the code you posted raises a `NameError`, please post examples that make sense as code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't modify `url` in the loop. For example:

```
url = "<base url>"
number = 0
while True:
     number +=1
     html = urllib2.urlopen('{}?curpage={}'.format(url, number)).read()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url = url + ...
```

says to *add* to the end of `url`, making it longer with each iteration

From your expected output, you would seem to want:

```
html = urllib2.urlopen(url+'?curpage={}'.format(number)).read()
```

Also, your loop will never end.

Answer (score 0):

```
number = 0
for i in range(10):
    url = 'http://www.example.com/'
    number = number + 1
    url = url + '?curpage={}'.format(number)
    print (url)
```